# Differences swap to file and (usual) swap for VMware guest

Tags: vmware, swap, swap-file

I would like to ask about the main differences of "swap no hibernate" and "swap to file" in case of a virtual machine.

By default I choose swap without hibernate because that's always going well, but I wonder if there are any benefits of "swap to file" in a VMware Workstation guest environment. And what's common?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Swap** is usually set up as a separate partition from the operating system root, and takes up a fixed amount of space because of this. (plus at least as much disk space as your VM's total RAM if you enable hibernate). This one is the most common. Sometimes you might even want to set up swap on a different physical disk for speed/cost reasons, and vmware can make that simple if it's just a separate .vmdk you can move around.

**Swap to file** allows that space to grow and shrink as required, which lets your OS use more of the available disk space. It's much easier to reconfigure later too, however you do risk crashes if you run low on OS disk space and memory at the same time.

Depending on the guest OS and/or vmtools version, VMWare may be better at recognizing one setting or the other for thin-provisioned VM disks. Otherwise there should be no difference. Guest OS swap is totally separate from the VM swap (.vswp) files which can get used by the host.

Answer (score 0):

If you pick swap without hibernate, you'll get a smaller swap area.

If you pick swap with hibernate, you'll get swap with the size of
the RAM you have allocated or slightly larger, so that when
hibernating the guest, all RAM contents can be written to swap.

Swap to file is the puzzling one - my guess is that this creates
the swap area inside a host file which can grow without a fixed limit.